# On screen Keyboard with uTouch

Tags: unity, tablet, multi-touch

I want to buy a Mecer LUCID Slate tablet and install unity on the tablet. Thus no keyboard.

1. Clicking on a text entry field will this bring up a on screen keyboard?
2. Does uTouch support a on screen keyboard out of the box or do you have to install a package to have this capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Unity does not come with an onscreen keyboard of that sort. You can use [onboard](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/onboard)  (open it from dash) to type using the mouse/touchpad, though it won't be a wonderfully smooth experience. Unfortunately there is no "Ubuntu Tablet Edition", so until (if) that happens, you will have to resort to "hacks" or "workarounds" to get such functionality.

Onboard screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Dash isn't a standard package... How else can one open it on a keyboard-free system?

Comment: what are you referring to?

Comment: Ok, so far this is working pretty fine out of the box in an HP Slate 2 in Ubuntu 14.04.2. I yet have an issue on how to switch OS in a dual boot touch screen system with no physical keyboard. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion florence virtual keyboard seems like the best onscreen keyboard currently available for linux.

Download it from [sourceforge.net](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html) and compile or install with a [deb](http://code.google.com/p/ardesia/downloads/detail?name=florence-ramble_0.2-debian-1_amd64.deb&can=2&q=)  (older version )

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the above answer, I think onboard isgood with the right keyboard layouts. If you install ubuntu netbook, you can pin onboard to the side-menu, and then tap on it whenever you need to type.

Trust me, im typing this from my acer tablet.

I think ubuntu is already quite touch-friendly... just search around to make sure somebody else has already got the touchscreen working on your device.